# Git via Gerrit: local/master out of sync with origin/master

Tags: git, gerrit

There are several questions opened against `"Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by X commits."`... However, I could not fix from the solutions I provided.

Here is my scenario:

I have a working gerrit environment and I have the privileges to bypass review.

`git status` yields:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

on seeing my branch is ahead of `remote` I try to push my branch.

`git push gerrit:project master

     Everything up-to-date`

So I try to `pull`

`git pull gerrit:project`

`From gerrit:project`

`* branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD`

`Already up-to-date.`

`git status` again yields the same status of `my branch ahead of 'origin/master' by X commits`

when I `diff master origin/master` I get no changes.

Please let me know if I can assist you with outputs of other commands..

thanks for looking at this.

Comment: You use two remote repositories. You push and pull to gerrit:project, but status blames origin. Did you try to do `git pull origin`, `git push origin master`?

Comment: Thanks for your response! please correct me if I am wrong: my belief is that `origin/master` in my case refers to `gerrit:project` ? given this assumption of mine is correct, I did do `git pull origin` and `git push origin master`...which I think translates to corresponding commands `git pull gerrit:project` and `git push gerrit:project master` respectively

Comment: Try `git remote -v`. You will see exact URLs associated with your repos. If they are different, then most likely repos are too. Anyway, do you actually need to use aliases for the same repo? It seems strange. If not, you'd better remove one of aliases via `git remote rm <repo-to-remove>`.

Comment: `git pull` and `git push` (without args) operates on repo where upstream branch lives if it is set. But it won't replace one repo with another. At least, I know nothing about such kind of repo aliasing.

Comment: I tried to add two remote repos with the same URL. It is possible, though I do not see reasons for such setup. Anyway, you better check if your repos actually point to the same URL with `git remote -v` as I pointed above.

Comment: @Rorick thanks for your helpful comments!. `git remote -v` yielded me the following: `origin  gerrit:crs2awips (fetch)
origin  gerrit:crs2awips (push)`. Regarding the repos, I have 2: first one is plain git and second one is gerrit on top of git. The `'gerrit:'` alias you see has been setup with my ssh config to allow multiple ssh configs (like work and personal)

Comment: Thanks @Rorick your answer pointed me in right direction...I deleted and 'recreated' the remote repos and it no longer gave me that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a different question on this forum and the answer to that question is related to this one as well.

To summarize here are some steps that can be done:

Consider using `push -f`

or delete "remotes" and update it like this:

`git remote -v` throws output

```
origin  gerrit:project (fetch)
origin  gerrit:project (push)
```

From [gitref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17577651/405117) add your remotes here and remove origin

`git remote add gerrit gerrit:project`
`git remote rm origin`
`git remote -v` which should show following:

```
gerrit  gerrit:project (fetch)
gerrit  gerrit:project (push)
```

Here is the reference to [that question of my mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17577651/405117)...which has been answered.

Please feel free to close as I think this would be duplicate of my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17577651/405117)

Answer (score 0):

git push -f didn't seem to do anything for me. Here's what worked in my case.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~n
```

Replace n with how ever many commits your ahead by. Sometimes it takes a few times.

```
git pull
```

You should be at the correct location in the repo now without being 'related' to other commits in Gerrit.