# git clone fetches HEAD but git pull does not fetch the latest HEAD after Merge Push operation on a Gerrit Repo

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a Git Repository and Gerrit review runs on top of this. I have Push/ Push Merge Commit privileges on this repo (which means I can bypass a Gerrit Review and merge code directly as if Gerrit did not exist).

As a part of routine activity, I `merged` a completed topic(passed and approved in Gerrit) into my master

`git merge master-b734912`

`Updating 08f272e..d265243` *This step means my local/master `HEAD` on SHA-1 `08f272e` fast-forwarded to `d265243` which is as expected*

`Fast-forward`

followed by a `push` to sync up my local with remote

`git push gerrit:projectname master` *The 'gerrit:' alias is defined in ssh config in my user profile*

I pull back from remote/master to ensure everything is in sync

`git pull gerrit:projectname master` on which I get

`From gerrit:crs2awips
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.`

However `git log --graph --oneline master` shows the updated tree with the new commit as expected

```
* d265243 git commit message 2
*   08f272e git commit message 1
```

Whereas `git log --graph --oneline origin/master` still shows the last commit before merge.

```
*   08f272e git commit message 1'
```

**What is even more surprising is that Gerrit Review Web UI shows remote having the commit as updated.**

**Additionally, cloning the repository now will have a `master` branch with commit-id as expected.**

From the above I conclude...somehow locally `HEAD` is not updated after `git pull` and throws it out of sync after every push.

It is kind of inconvenient to clone a fresh repo each time after a `PUSH` has been done.

Any advice.

Recently I also raised [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557815/git-via-gerrit-local-master-out-of-sync-with-origin-master) issue. I believe that issue has some connection to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I am answering my own question here.

In my opinion what might have happened is that  link to remotes (references to remote repositories i.e. do `git branch -a`. The branches that begin with "remotes/*" is what I am referring here) remained "stale" for some reason I do not understand.

Before my suggestion as a quick check try these steps:

`git status` should throw message

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by X commit(s).
# 
blah blah blah...
```

when I see this message my instinct is to do a `push`

`git push remote master` ...in this case I was working on master, for which I get

`Everything up-to-date` which maybe confusing and I go and do a `git status` for which the same message reappears:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by X commit(s).
# 
blah blah blah...
```

use `push -f` option and check `git status` to see if the message disappears.

If you still get the same confusing(but correct) message you should probably be suspicious of your remote.

One of comments in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17557815/405117) pointed me in the right direction.

listing the steps here:

`git remote -v` throws output

```
origin  gerrit:project (fetch)
origin  gerrit:project (push)
```

From [gitref](http://gitref.org/remotes/) add your remotes here and remove origin

`git remote add gerrit gerrit:project`
`git remote rm origin`
`git remote -v` which should show following:

```
gerrit  gerrit:project (fetch)
gerrit  gerrit:project (push)
```

Now do a `push -f` as follows

`git push -f gerrit master` will probably yield 
`Everything up-to-date` ...but this time it really meant it ;-)

on `git status` receive

`# On branch master`

`nothing to commit (working directory clean)`